# DateTime offset in Google BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have some trouble with Google BigQuery

I need to build result in timezone **UTC+05:45**, but i get this error

> DATE_ADD 2nd argument must have INT32 type.

query example

```
SELECT DATE(DATE_ADD(time, 5.75, 'HOUR')) AS day, ... FROM ... WHERE ... AND  ( DATE_ADD(time, 5.75, "HOUR") >= '2015-05-01 00:00:00' AND  DATE_ADD(time, 5.75, "HOUR") < '2015-06-01 00:00:00' ) GROUP EACH BY day  ORDER BY day asc LIMIT 2000
```

This code correctly work with any others offsets (+03:00, -05:30, etc), but with +05:45 - i get this error

Do you have any ideas about that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are 5 hour behind UTC, you need to use a workaround:

```
UTC_USEC_TO_DAY(timestamp_field- (5*60*60*1000*1000000) )
```

Timezone functions, is on feature request list as documented here: https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?id=8

Comment: I would 'star' this issue. The more stars the higher the priority it will get.